# How to test API that calls a service and that service calls a repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, repository, web-api-testing

I have four projects that need to be tested (my design patter is similar to this https://exceptionnotfound.net/the-repository-service-pattern-with-dependency-injection-and-asp-net-core/). The first project is a data access layer project that fetches data from the database. The second one is a repository project that just makes CRUD operations on the entities in the database through the data access layer project.
Here's an example of how the generic interface in the repository project looks like which is implemented for all the entities in the database,

```
public interface IEntityBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IEntityBase, new()
    {
        IEnumerable<T> AllIncluding(
          params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties
        );
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        int Count();
        T GetSingle(int id);
        T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T GetSingle(
          Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate,
          params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties
        );
        IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T Add(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void DeleteWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        void Commit();
    }
```

The third project is a service project that cater for the logic required by the application. It deals with the repository project and creates objects and functions based on the need of the system. Here's an extract of one of the service in the project,

```
    public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
    {
        private IEntityBaseRepository<Employee> _employeeRepository;
        private IEntityBaseRepository<User> _userRepository;
        private IEntityBaseRepository<UserRole> _userRoleRepository;
        private IEntityBaseRepository<Role> _roleRepository;
        public EmployeeService(IEntityBaseRepository<Employee> employeeRepository, IEntityBaseRepository<User> userRepository, IEntityBaseRepository<UserRole> userRoleRepository, IEntityBaseRepository<Role> roleRepository)
        {
            _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
            _userRoleRepository = userRoleRepository;
            _roleRepository = roleRepository;
        }
        .
        .
        .
        public List<EmployeeServiceModel> GetAllEmployeesForUser(string username)
        {
            var user = _userRepository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
            var userRoles = _userRoleRepository.GetAll().Where(ur => ur.UserId == user.Id);
            var roles = _roleRepository.GetAll();
            var currentRoles = new List<Role>(); 
         
            if (userRoles != null && userRoles.Count() > 0)
            {
                currentRoles = roles.Where(r => userRoles.Any(ur => ur.RoleId == r.Id)).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(); 
            }
            . 
            . 
            .
```

As you can see from the above, it depends on the repository project.

Finally, API project that exposes the services to the world

```
public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase
{
    private IEmployeeService _employeeService;

    public EmployeesController(IEmployeeService employeeService)
    {
        _employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    // GET: api/<EmployeesController>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string username)
    {
        var employees = _employeeService.GetAllEmployeesForUser(username); 
        return Ok(employees);
    }
```

The problem is, how can unit test the above solution? Should I just test the API's? If yes, how can do that? The project depends on the service interface which in turn depends on the repositories. I cannot just create a fake list of employees and make the "GetAllEmployeesForUser" function in the service return them. How about if I want to test when a user is unauthorised, or doesn't have employees?
Should I just test the service project? And no need to test the API's?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the whole web API (integration tests) you can find all info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0

If you want to do unit tests, you can mock parts that you don't need in specific test case with `Moq` or `Substitute` libraries and perform execution in parts where you want to test. For instance, if you want to test only EmployeeService logic:

```cs
var employeesRepMock = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<Employee>>();
var usersRepMock =  new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<User>>();
var userRolesRepMock = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<UserRole>>();
var rolesRepMock = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<Role>>();

rolesRepMock.Setup(m => m.GetAll().Returns(new List<Role> {
 // test roles here
}));
usersRepMock.Setup(m => m.GetAll().Returns(new List<User> {
 // test users here
}));
employeesRepMock.Setup(m => m.GetAll().Returns(new List<Employee> {
 // test employees here
}));
userRolesRepMock.Setup(m => m.GetAll().Returns(new List<UserRoles> {
 // test user roles here
}));

var service = new EmployeeService(employeesRepMock.Object, 
   usersRepMock.Object, userRolesRepMock.Object, rolesRepMock.Object);

var result = service.GetAllEmployeesForUser("test-username");

// your checks ..
Assert.Greater(result.Length, 0);
```

To test the EF Core logic, you can use InMemory database.

Comment: How if i want to unit test my api? In this case how can i mock the service which relies on the repository?

Comment: If you want to mock a service, you can do it like I did with repositories: `var serviceMock = new Mock<IEmployeeService>()`. **In this case `IEmployeeService` won't use any repository which it depends on**. And then you can configure some calls for each (as I remember by default any method of mocked will return default value of return type): `serviceMock.Setup(s => s.GetAllEmployeesForUser(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new List< EmployeeServiceModel >())`;

Comment: Make sure that service which you want to mock implements an interface. Under the hood framework creates implementation of this interface and handle all the calls, getters, setters and etc made to mocked object. So your original implementation won't be used like `EmployeeService` class for `IEmployeeService` interface

Comment: How about if I want to test the API call when a user is unauthorised, or doesn't have employees? API in this case should return unauthorised or something like that. How can I generate repositories when that user is not authorised or in other words dont have a manager role? How can the employeeService know that without calling the repositories? I think mocking the IEmployeeService is not enough here right?